# How to solve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.flush()V error in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I read from a Kafka topic some messages and for each rdd the function `proccess_rdds` is executed.

```
def spark_streaming_online():

    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("spark://antonis:7077").setAppName("Kafka_Spark")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc,2)

    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                                        ['enriched_messages'],
                                        {"metadata.broker.list":"my-broker"},
                                        valueDecoder=lambda x: x)
    lines = kvs.window(60,2).map(lambda x: x[1])
    lines.foreachRDD(lambda y: proccess_rdds(y))


    return ssc

 ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate('/home/antonis/Desktop/tmp/checkpoint_v06',lambda: spark_streaming_online())
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I cannot post here all the contents from `proccess_rdds` because is huge. I post the code where the error occurs (at least I think so).

```
ds = df \
     .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
     .write \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "my-broker") \
     .option("topic", "compressed_messages") \
     .save()
```

The error says:

> An error occurred while calling o186.save. :
>
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 14 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   14.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 34, 192.168.1.69, executor 0): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.flush()V

I submit this python script with:

`/usr/spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5 --jars /home/antonis/Desktop/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.5.jar spark_streamer.py`

Spark version: 2.4.5

It is very strange that this script sometimes works without the error. I suspect that something is wrong with the versions.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You probably right, some of your code tries to execute `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.flush()` and the method is not found.  Any particular reason not using structured streaming? You are using the latest Spark 2.4.5 version with an almost deprecated API (DStream)

Comment: No there is not a particular reason and I removed structured streams. Works good with classic producer.send()

Comment: I am afraid you have to dig into the Spark implementation and try to find out the code which calls `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.flush()` then try to provide the correct `spark-sql-kafka` version

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```